# Vertical zoom on individual series or Y-axis in Echarts

Tags: echarts

Is it possible to zoom on individual series in Echarts? By that I mean selecting a series and then applying vertical zoom on that series while the other series remain unchanged.

I have looked at the examples and documentation, but can´t find it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible and supported. The way I did it was by setting `zoomOnMouseWheel` on idividual series through setOption.

Selecting a series by clicking on it seems a little brittle though. The selections don´t always seem to go through. I used the `selectchanged` event.